# Proving that liouville's constant is transcendental with guided steps

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory

So i got this guided question that basically proves why liouville's constant is transcendental. Here is the Question:
let $\alpha=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 10^{-k!}$ be liouville's constant, in this drill we will see that $\alpha$ is transcendental in $\mathbb{Q}$.

1. Prove that $\alpha$ is irrational.
2. Let $f=a_nx^n+...+a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, and let $\frac{p}{q}$ be a rational number which is not a root of $f$. prove that $|f(\frac{p}{q})|\geq \frac{1}{q^n}$
3. Now we assume that $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ and $\frac{p}{q}\in(\alpha-1,\alpha+1)$ and closer to $\alpha$ more that to any other root of $f$. Because $f$ is a polynomal that implies that exits a constant $M$ that for every $y\in(\alpha-1,\alpha+1)$, $|f^{'}(y)|\leq M$. prove that $|\frac{p}{q}-\alpha|\geq\frac{1}{Mq^n}$.
4. Conclude that for every $r>n$ there exits only a finite number of rationals $\frac{p}{q}$ so: $|\frac{p}{q}-\alpha|<\frac{1}{q^r}$.
5. Explain why this is a contradiction to the definition of $\alpha$ and conclude that $\alpha$ is transcendental.

I managed to solve the first three parts of the drill (in part 3 i used the mean-value theorem).
My problem is the other two steps (4 and 5) , I would appreciate it if someone will help me with those last steps.
Thanks for the helpers. 
In general, how would you prove that there are only a finite number of rationals in a case similar to this

Comment: What about the last two parts troubles you?

Comment: I cant find a way to prove that there exits only a finite number of rationals... I tried to aim for contradicion by assuming there is an Infinte number of rationals but I dont know how to continue

Comment: By part 3, for every rational $\frac{p}{q}$ as in 4, you have $$\frac{1}{Mq^n} < \frac{1}{q^r}\,,$$ which entails $q^{r-n} < M$. Thus there are only finitely many possible denominators. Show that for every possible denominator there are only finitely many numerators such that $\lvert \alpha - p/q\rvert < 1/q^r$,